# How to unmarshal xml without mapping the root xml element?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to unmarshal a xml file containing a collection of data, like this

```
 <Persons>
      <Person>Jim</Person>
      <Person>Tom</Person>  
  </Persons>
```

We know this can be done with two classess: Persons, Person using Castor , JAXB, or other frameworks.

But how to do without writing a collection class Persons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a way to tell Castor that you'd like it to generate a `java.util.List` of Person instances.

http://www.castor.org/how-to-map-a-list-at-root.html

Comment: I am facing the same issue. However, the above URL is redirecting to a fwdservice. Do you have an updated URL?

Comment: Nope, I don't.  Google might help more than me.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB:

- Iterate over subelements of the incoming XML (DOM, SAX, StAX - whatever API suits you best)
- `unmarshaller.unmarshal(node, Person.class)`

There are also advanced techniques with programmaticaly created mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a StAX parser and do something like the following with any JAXB implementation (Metro, EclipseLink MOXy, Apache JaxMe, etc):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

        FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to "Persons" tag 
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to "Person" tag

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        while(xsr.hasNext() && xsr.isStartElement()) {
            Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
            persons.add(person);
            xsr.nextTag();
        }

        for(Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<Persons>
    <Person>Jim</Person>
    <Person>Tom</Person>  
</Persons>
```

**System Output**

```
Jim
Tom
```

**Person**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class Person {

    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```