# Simple XML Framework parse only part of the XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I am using the Simple XML framework to parse responses from a soap web service. I only want to parse the actual web service response and ignore the soap envelope and body (i.e. I don't want to have Envelope and Body classes for all my responses).

XML:

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <TopGoalScorersResponse>
            <TopGoalScorersResult>
                <tTopGoalScorer>
                    <sName>Alan Dzagoev</sName>
                    <iGoals>3</iGoals>
                    <sCountry>Y</sCountry>
                    <sFlag>http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/images/flags/ru.gif</sFlag>
                    <sFlagLarge>http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/images/flags/ru.png</sFlagLarge>
                </tTopGoalScorer>
            </TopGoalScorersResult>
        </TopGoalScorersResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

So for this response I want to have TopGoalScorersResponse, TopGoalScorersResult and TopGoalScorer classes and not be required to have an Envelope and Body class.

Is this possible?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Java Xpath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/) for getting a parts by xpath query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a StAX parser to parse the XML document.  Then you could use the resulting `XMLStreamReader` to advance to the element that you wish to start with and then unmarshal from there (assuming Simple XML can unmarshal from a StAX `XMLStreamReader`).

Below is a link to an answer where I did something very similar but with [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6414517/383861

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is achieved using @Path

So, you'll have

```
@Root(strict=false, name="Envelope")  
public class Root {
    @Path("Body")
    @Element(inline=true)
    private TopGoalScorersResult topGoalScorersResult;
}
```