# Using JAXB to unmarshal common elements of different XML documents

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have a number of XML documents that all have a common inner structure that looks something like:

```
<Fields>
    <Field>
        <Name>foo</Name>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>bar</Name>
    </Field>
</Fields>
```

Each different document is similar only in that the structure of the "Fields" element is the same. The root element and surrounding elements may differ.

Example document 1:

```
<ObjectX>
    <Fields>
        <Field>
            <Name>foo</Name>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <Name>bar</Name>
        </Field>
    </Fields>
</ObjectX>
```

Example document 2:

```
<Object-Y>
    <Section1>
        <Fields>
            <Field>
                <Name>foo</Name>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Name>bar</Name>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Section1>
</Object-Y>
```

Is it possible to use JAXB to unmarshal just the "Fields" element of all documents without having to set up Java classes that correspond to the elements I don't care about?

Based on several answers to similar questions, I tried a few things but to no avail.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a StAX `XMLStreamReader` on the XML documents.  The advance it to the `Fields` element and then unmarshal it from that state.

**Examples**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6414517/383861
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html